# Escape windows file path in docker sql string

Tags: t-sql, docker, sqlcmd

Im trying to build a sql server docker image that has a previous backup already mounted. My docker file looks like this (I know the restore command isnt correct):

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer

RUN mkdir "C:\\SQLServer"

COPY Backup.bak C:\\SQLServer

ENV sa_password=verysecurepassword

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

RUN sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [MyDatabase] FROM DISK = N'C:\\SQLServer\\Backup.bak' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, NORECOVERY, STATS = 5"
```

When i run docker build with this file, i get the following error:

`Sqlcmd: 'DATABASE [MyDatabase] FROM DISK = NC:\\SQLServer\\Backup.bak WITH FILE = 1 NOUNLOAD REPLACE NOR
= 5': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.`

As you can see, it has stripped out the single quotes around the filepath. I tried escaping the single quotes (with backslashes), but the quotes still get stripped out, leaving the extra backslashes in the path aswell.

If i run sqlcmd on the container directly, i can run the restore command (and get an error about files not being copied, which is expected). What is the format for embedding windows paths in dockerfile sql strings?

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the double quotes around the SQL with a \ for Docker

You should escape the single quotes around the file name with a ` for Powershell

```
RUN sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -Q \"RESTORE DATABASE [MyDatabase] FROM DISK = N`'C:\\SQLServer\\Backup.bak`' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, NORECOVERY, STATS = 5\"
```